# How to prevent back to homepage after f5/refreshpage from dashboard

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem when i creating a web for myself. when i login and go to dashboard. and when some code edited will refresh the page but back to login page again / always logout. this is after i refresh the page in dashboard. my question, how to prevent back to login or prevent logout after refresh the page. this is for react js. thank you, from the newbie

Comment: You need to, somehow, persist that the login has happened. Maybe with localstorage

Comment: localsotrage? webrobswer localstorage?

Comment: use cookies maybe?